# Sort full set based off sorted subset

Tags: algorithm, sorting, subset

Say I have a previously sorted list: **ABCDEF**. The user can filter off some of these items to end up with a subset say: **BCEF**. In the subset, the user is then allowed to reorder those items. For example, they move the **B** to be after the **E**, now the subset is: **CEBF**. Then they turn off the filter. I want the original list to reflect the re-sorted subset. So the full list should now look like: **ACDEBF**.

What sorting technique am I looking for here? Other possibly pertinent information:

1. At the subset stage, the user can only move one item at a time
2. The filter could create a subset that is any number of items; it could be the full list, it could just be two items (technically it could go down to 0, but the 0 & 1 cases become trivial since there's no way for the user to re-sort the subset)
3. Items in the original list that weren't in the subset should retain they're position as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
sorted_fullset = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
sorted_subset = ["a","b","e"]

def shuffle_set_by_subset(sorted_fullset,sorted_subset,shuffled_subset):
  shuffle = dict((item,idx) for idx,item in enumerate(sorted_subset))
  shuffled_fullset = sorted_fullset[:]
  for idx,item in enumerate(sorted_fullset):
    if item in sorted_subset:
      place_in_sorted_subset = shuffle[item]
      shuffled_fullset[idx] = shuffled_subset[place_in_sorted_subset]
  return shuffled_fullset

print shuffle_set_by_subset(sorted_fullset,sorted_subset,["e","b","a"])
print shuffle_set_by_subset(sorted_fullset,sorted_subset,["a","e","b"])
```

Results in:

```
['e', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'f']
['a', 'e', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'f']
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a pre-sorted list, whenever a sub-set is created, make a note of the positions of the items in the sub-set w.r.t the original set. (For example use another array to track the positions).

Then ensure that while the items are re-arranged, the indexes remain the same (Is so by default if using a separate array).

Finally copy back the re-arranged items to the positions indicated by the index-array.

Eg: A = {a,b,c,d,e,f}. B_ITEMS = {b,d,e}. B_POSITIONS = {2,4,5}

Lets say items in B are re-arranged as follows :
B_ITEMS = {d,e,b}

Copy the items in B_ITEMS to the positions indicated by B_POSITIONS.

A = {a,d,c,e,b,f}

Comment: Thanks. I effectively did that, but without explicitly using an additional array. I had the original array A={a,b,c,d,e,f} with original subset B={b,d,e}. Subset gets resorted to C={d,e,b}. Then I set up two pointers, one on the original array, pA, and one on the resorted subset, pC. Then I start incrementing down A setting items according to the following rules: if the item pA points to is NOT in C, leave it in place and advance pA. If the pA item is in C, then insert the item pointed to by pC and increment both pA and pC.

Comment: Not able to get you fully but glad you sorted it out. Pointers can be tricky. Also do test for duplicate letters !